# How to set highlighting of do-end blocks in Sublime Text 3 for ruby?

Tags: ruby, sublimetext3

For example: Sublime Text highlights opening and closing html-tags. How to make a similar effect for do-end blocks? I did not find the settings or packages in packagecontrol for similar effect.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think you are looking for **BracketHighlighter** package. 
I use it and works well with Sublime Text 3!

https://github.com/facelessuser/BracketHighlighter

Check it out this commit :) https://github.com/facelessuser/BracketHighlighter/commit/306b56e21db64e38e46e2f46a74df1cde0816bad